# Allow Numbers and Special Characters only not alphabets

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-3.0

i have a textbox, in that i want to restrict the alphabets only, that is it will accept only numbers and special charcaters not alphabets..

i had tried the below java script ,but it will not working ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Function to allow only numbers to textbox
    function validate(key) {
        //getting key code of pressed key
        var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;        
        //comparing pressed keycodes

        if (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) {
            return false;
        }       
    } 
    </script>
```

and in the textbox

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtoldpwd_TextChanged"
                            onkeypress="return validate(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: "it will not working" doesn't describe how the actual behaviour isn't the same as the desired behaviour. (The fact that you're returning a value in one case but not the other seems odd to me...) It's also not at all clear what this really has to do with C#. Is the expected Javascript reaching the browser? If so, it's *just* a Javascript issue, and you can diagnose/fix it without involving ASP.NET at all.

Comment: 1. You have a typo in the `if` statement (`keyCode` instead of `keycode`) 2. the range 65-90 is for uppercase letters and after fixing the typo it doesn't allow to type them in, so it kind of works 3. don't use keyboard-related events for validation (doesn't prevent pasting invalid characters).

Answer (score 3):

Write script as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate(event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9-!@#$%*?]");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }       
</script>
```

and call like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcheck" onkeypress="return Validate(event);" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
$('input').keypress(function(e){
var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
console.log(txt + ' : ' + e.which);
if(!txt.match(/[A-Za-z+#.]/))
{
return false;
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function AllowAlphabet(evt) {
 var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
 if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
 return true;
 else
return false;
}
```

Comment: May it help for you

Comment: it allows everything number, letters , special char

Answer (score -1):

You can  use regular expression validator. Here is

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1"
    ErrorMessage="Enter a valid number" ValidationExpression="^\d+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Or if you want to use JavaScript:

Try this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/328178/Allow-only-Numeric-values-in-ASP-Text-box-control