# Allow only special characters and numbers - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me to allow only special characters and numbers using jquery please. I have a text field where alphabet should not be entered.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password complexity regex with number or special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132154/password-complexity-regex-with-number-or-special-character)

Comment: Please refer to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227599/allow-numbers-and-special-characters-only-not-alphabets).

Comment: @RonyLoud, In your link I saw following function is familiar to me and when I tried it isn't working. Can you please edit it. function AllowAlphabet(evt) {
 var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
 if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
 return true;
 else
return false;
}

Comment: Can you define "special character"?

Comment: All special characters except alphabets should not be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Validate(event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9-!@#$%&*?]");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input ID="txtcheck" onkeypress="return Validate(event);" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked perfectly. but how can I allow other common keys such as backspace, enterkey, arrow left, arrow right, arrow up, arrow down, home key, end, page up, page down, and also ctrl + C and Ctrl + V

Answer (score 0):

In the latter part of your question you mentioned

> I have a text field where alphabet should not be entered.

Incase if you use HTML5, i suggest you could try below approach

```
<input type="text" name="specialfield" pattern="[^a-zA-Z]*" title="Alphabets not allowed">
```